# nalyse the code but not sure what they are doing at this line spyOn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, jasmine

- I am trying to understand jasmine test cases.
- they are doing a spyon for the grid.
- but I am not sure why they are doing for the grid.
- I did analyse the code but not sure what they are doing at this line and what is the use of return value
           spyOn(swimming.running.gridkendo,'remote').and.returnValue(null);
- can you guys explain so that I can write test case by myself.
- I did some research but not sure how to proceed.
- providing my code below.

test cases

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null**

```or-tag-here
let swimming: laughing;

         spyOn(swimming.running.gridkendo,'remote').and.returnValue(null);
         swimming.running.shopping(values);
```

code

```or-tag-here
shopping(values)
  {
    console.log("I am here---> shopping");
    var grid = $('#ringGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    console.log("I am here 2---> shopping" + grid);
        //console.log("I am here 2---> shopping" + JSON.stringify(grid));


    var school = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    grid.dataSource.remove(school);
    //  var shopping = record_to_delete;
    //  shopping.remove();

    $('#cap').hide();
}
```

Comment: `jasminespy.and.returnValue(value)` just sets up the spy to return a specific value, when the method is called (as a spy by default won't return anything). Also it is hard to understand the problem only by seeing the code you have provided. Pleas have a look at [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hey why they are setting up return value... without return value can't we write any test cases... what is the advantage??

Comment: The advantage is that you can suppress calls to (external) services, which are not under test. Of course you wont create a spy for the method you are going to test.

Comment: Can you give an example in the code...it's so confusing :(

Comment: Have a look at the link I provided, to update your question please

Comment: Why they are using remoteValue parameter and null in return....can we use any other value in the return??

Comment: Or depending upon any scenario I need to use??